# Can I use Braintree SDK(special me need Apple Pay) with PayPal Gateway?

Tags: paypal, sdk, braintree, gateway

I have a task, I need append to my client project Apple Pay.
But we have integrated payment system Paypal.
I researched Paypal SDK and found official information about stopping support PayPal SDK in 2013 and then below advice, use Braintree SDK.
For using Braintree SDK I need create account in official web-site. where me need upload certificate and on page below a sow public and private key, merchantID.
My question, if I integrate Braintree SDK on my client application I can use PayPal gateway for my Braintree SDK.
If it real I will be grateful you for link on information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Braintree definitely supports processing both Apple Pay and PayPal payments. For PayPal, you'll end up using the PayPal Business Account that you already have setup.

I recommend [signing up for a sandbox account](https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox) to test the functionality. Once you've signed up for a sandbox account, Braintree's developer docs have information on how to [integrate PayPal](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/javascript/v3) and [Apple Pay](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/overview) into your web/mobile app.

If you have any further questions while testing an integration, I highly recommend contacting [Braintree's Support Team](https://help.braintreepayments.com).